# Making ProductItem.Status work with WebService APIv2

Tags: .net, magento, soap

I'm building an application that integrates with the magento commerce engine, and I've got through most of the issues with the API, but I'm stuck trying to get the `Status` to work when I'm adding a new product

```
_mage.catalogProductCreateEntity si = new _mage.catalogProductCreateEntity();
```

//...lots of other attributes setup correctly

```
si.status = "Enabled";

productID = ms.catalogProductCreate(sessionID, "simple", mSettings.ProductAttributeSetID.ToString, posProductcode, si, "default");
```

the product is getting created in the database correctly, but it is neither Enabled or Disabled, and requires a manual edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after Looking hard this turns out to be pretty easy.

```
si.status="1";
```

And that is "Enabled" and "0" for Disabled.